# What is the correct way to see if an arbitrary object is a JPA entity?

Tags: jpa

The [`javax.persistence.EntityManager#contains(Object)` method's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) says (in part):

> Check if the instance is a managed entity instance belonging to the current persistence context.
>   **Throws:**
>   `IllegalArgumentException` - if not an entity

Section 3.1.1 of the [JPA 2.1 specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338) says:

> Runtime exceptions [such as `IllegalArgumentException`] thrown by the methods of the `EntityManager` interface [such as `contains(Object)`] other than the `LockTimeoutException` will cause the current transaction to be marked for rollback if the persistence context is joined to that transaction.

What, then, is the preferred way to check if an arbitrary object (don't know whether it's an entity, don't know whether it's in the persistence context) is both an entity and in the persistence context without rolling back the current transaction?

Comment: In what context are you: Java EE or SE? If EE, what application server do you use No matter your context, have you tried my code (maybe adapted if SE)?

Comment: EclipseLink as shipped with GlassFish 3.1.2.2.  Invoking `contains()` on an arbitrary non-entity object rolls the transaction back unless I'm missing or confusing something.

Comment: Even if the Exception is immediately caught? Have you tried exactly my code?

Comment: Use the static metamodel, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307727/how-to-know-if-a-class-is-an-entity-javax-persistence-entity/49348744#49348744.

Answer (score 0):

You could check that in a new transaction, which does not affect your current transaction.

---

**Some notices**
This is a good example for your last question, when I answered that there are parts of the specification that are not correctly formulated. I will give you an example, which works without any problems, which contradicts the specification (at least in JBoss 7.1 with Hibernate):

```
public class EjbServiceBean implement EjbService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void testTransaction() {

        //this code is in a transaction EJB method
        MyEntity entity = em.find(MyEntity.class, 1L);
        entity.setPeristentField("New Value");

        try {
            em.find(Class.class, 1);//should rollback the transaction
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //simply catching the Exception, so that the CMT transaction is not rolled back by the EJB container.
        }
    //but after the method returns, the entity instance is commited.
    }
}
```

With this example I mean you could in practice use the `em.contains()` method to check whether a class is an entity class or not.

PS: This is specified also in the 2.0 specification.