# How to know if a class is an @Entity (javax.persistence.Entity)?

Tags: jpa, entity, instanceof

How can I know if a class is annotated with `javax.persistence.Entity`?

**Person (Entity)**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_person")
public class Person {
...
}
```

**PersonManager**

```
@Stateless
public class PersonManager {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    public Person findById(int id) {
        Person person = this.em.find(Person.class, id);
        return person;
    }
```

I try to do it with instance of as the following

```
@Inject
PersonManager manager;

Object o = manager.findById(1);
o instanceof Entity  // false
```

however the result is `false`, shouldn't it be `true`?

Comment: That is a very fine question.

Answer (score 2):

While the existing answers provide a (somehow) working solution, some things should be noted:

1. Using an approach based on Reflection implies (a) Performance Overhead and (b) Security Restrictions (see [Drawbacks of Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)).
2. Using an ORM-specific (here: Hibernate) approach risks portability of the code towards other execution environments, i.e., application containers or other customer-related settings.

Luckily, there is a third *JPA*-only way of detecting whether a certain Java class (type) is a (managed) `@Entity`. This approach makes use of standardized access to the `javax.persistence.metamodel.MetaModel`. With it you get the method

> Set < EntityType > getEntities();

It only lists types annotated with `@Entity` AND which are detected by the current instance of EntityManager you use. With every object of `EntityType` it is possible to call

> Class< ? > getJavaType();

For demonstration purposes, I quickly wrote a method which requires an instance of `EntityManager` (here: `em`), either injected or created ad-hoc:

```
private boolean isEntity(Class<?> clazz) {
    boolean foundEntity = false;
    Set<EntityType<?>> entities = em.getMetamodel().getEntities();
    for(EntityType<?> entityType :entities) {
        Class<?> entityClass = entityType.getJavaType();
        if(entityClass.equals(clazz)) {
            foundEntity = true;
        }
    }
    return foundEntity;
}
```

You can provide such a method (either public or protected) in a central place (such as a Service class) for easy re-use by your application components. The above example shall just give a direction of what to look for aiming at a pure *JPA* approach.

For reference see sections 5.1.1 (page 218) and 5.1.2 (page 219f) of the [JPA 2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the statement

```
sessionFactory.getClassMetadata( HibernateProxyHelper.getClassWithoutInitializingProxy( Person.class ) ) != null;
```

is true, than it is an entity.

Answer (score 1):

@NiVer's answer is valid. But, if you don't have a session or sessionFactory at that point you could use Reflection. Something like:

```
o.getClass().getAnnotation(Entity.class) != null;
```

Comment: The entity can be wrapped in proxy. Use `HibernateProxyHelper.getClassWithoutInitializingProxy(o).getAnnotation(Entity.class) != null`.